# Animation on a QPainterPath Object

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qpainterpath

I would like to display an animated arrow shape button.

To draw it, I creat a class which inheriths `QGraphicsObject`and use the `QPainterPath` class.

I draw it in a `QGraphicsScene` and animate it using the property `geometry`, re defined in MyArrow class.

You can find all the code here : https://github.com/TaiZzZ/arrowAnimation

My issue is the following :

The arrow animates (meaning it moves right and comes back) but stays painted while moving. Do you have any idea why ?

Ps : I have the same behaviour using [QState Machine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html), so I'm guessing the issue comes only from the way I draw my arrows.

I tried two different things :

- Changing the bezier curve into line, it doesn't fix the problem.
- Instead of drawing the path, I drew a rectangle(the `boundingRect()`) (So I only changed `drawPath(path)`), and it works

So to conclude, the bug comes from **QPainterPath** ... but why ?

EDIT :

Here are pictures to illustrate my problem :

[image: Before the animation]
[image: After the animation]

Note that it is no longer anti-alliased...

Comment: What do you mean by "stays painted while moving"?  Note also that your github repo appears to be incomplete -- I get "WARNING: Failure to find: mainwindow.ui" when I run `qmake`.

Comment: In deed I forgot that file, now it should work properly. 
"stays painted while moving" isn't very clear, but I don't know how to explain the issue shortly ! May be the best option is to had pictures, so please refer to the pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually quite straightforward -- you're not clearing your `QPainterPath` before reusing it.

Your `Arrow` class has a member...

```
QPainterPath arrow;
```

and your `Arrow::paint` implementation begins with...

```
arrow.moveTo(rect.right(),rect.center().y());
arrow.lineTo(rect.left(),rect.top());
```

So, each time `Arrow::paint` is called it's adding *another* new subpath to the `QPainterPath`.  Hence, at any given time what you see is the accumulated paths .  The simplest solution would be to remove the `arrow` member variable and use a locally scoped `QPainterPath`...

```
QPainterPath arrow;
arrow.moveTo(rect.right(),rect.center().y());
arrow.lineTo(rect.left(),rect.top());
```